# Is CloudFoundry compatible with Docker/CoreOS?

Tags: docker, openstack, cloud-foundry, openstack-nova, coreos

I am interested in installing OpenStack to a couple of physical we have lying around, and then, somehow, deploying CloudFoundry on top of of it, as the PaaS.

I am also interested in playing around with Docker and CoreOS, and see that an integration between [OpenStack and CoreOS](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/openstack/) already exists.

My question: if I have OpenStack/Nova spinning up VMs running CoreOS, and hence be Docker/container-based, **will this be compatible with CloudFoundry, or is CloudFoundry somehow incompatible with Docker containers?**

Comment: Thanks @MarkO'Connor (+1) - maybe I'm not fully understanding here, but I was under the impression that containers can't just stand on their own. They would require living inside a VM. So my thinking/hope was that I could use CloudFoundry to spin up VM instances, and inside those instances, deploy containers. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again @MarkO'Connor (+1 and feel free to add this as an answer for the green check ;-) ) - last followup, I promise: then what is the difference between CF Diego and Kubernetes, which also seems to be about deploying/distributing your container across pools of nodes? Do they serve different, similar or identical purposes? In other words, would there be a use case for having **both** CF Diego *and* Kubernetes managing your app deployments, if so, what? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Foundry is installed using a specialised tool called Bosh. It has support for Openstack and I think would require deployment using Ubuntu VMs (open to correction on this point). Cloud Foundry has not integrated Docker yet, that is coming in the next version, google "Cloud Foundry" and "Diego".

> maybe I'm not fully understanding here, but I was under the impression
>   that containers can't just stand on their own. They would require
>   living inside a VM. So my thinking/hope was that I could use
>   CloudFoundry to spin up VM instances, and inside those instances,
>   deploy containers. Thoughts?

Containers are completely standalone, they are a form of lightweight virtualization. Cloud Foundry is a platform for deploying your application. It runs on virtual machines (or physical servers) and instances of your application are compiled and run on the CF hosts within containers. Currently the container tech used by CF is something called Warden. Diego is a new CF component coming in 2015 that will offer Docker support.

> then what is the difference between CF Diego and Kubernetes, which
>   also seems to be about deploying/distributing your container across
>   pools of nodes? Do they serve different, similar or identical
>   purposes? In other words, would there be a use case for having both CF
>   Diego and Kubernetes managing your app deployments, if so, what?

Kubernetes is a Google sponsored project for orchestrating containers across multiple hosts. Cloud Foundry goes further because it also contains features for building and versioning applications that are deployed. It's worth noting that Redhat have a competing PAAS solution called Openshift. The next version (already available in github) has integrated Kubernetes and added in all the missing application build support, making it comparable to what Cloud Foundry offers. Both [CF Diego](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2014/09/cloud-foundry-diego-explained-onsi-fakhouri) and [Openshift V3](https://blog.openshift.com/tag/v3/) are due for delivery sometime in 2015.

## Update

- I see from your other questions, you're familiar with Camel. You'd be interested in the [fabric8 framework](http://fabric8.io/docs/index.html) which has recently integrated  Openshift V3. (Fabric is the upstream project for the JBoss Fuse product)

Comment: Thanks again @Mark O'Connor (+1) - so is it safe to say that I could use CF Diego for building, versioning and deploying my Docker containers, but then use Kubernates for orchestrating them across multiple hosts?  If not, then how have I misunderstood you? And if so, then what do you mean (specifically) by "Kubernetes **orchestrates** containers across **multiple hosts**"? What do you mean by "orchestrate"? By "multiple hosts", do you mean VMs? Thanks again!

Comment: Openshift and Cloud Foundry are competing products. It is Openshift V3 that has been re-engineered to integrate Kubernetes, using it to launch containers. Redhat are adding new features on top of Kubernetes (working with Google) enabling applications to be built from source and automatically uploaded to an internal Docker registry (Similar workflow offered by Cloud Foundry). In summary, Openshift is a PAAS that is more fully embracing 3rd party standards. Cloud Foundry is a more opinionated solution, preferring to abstract the details. Either are a good solution to adopt.

Comment: Thanks (yet again) @Mark O'Connor (+1) - however I feel like you misinterpreted my question above. I wasn't asking for a comparison between CF Diego and OpenShift V3, I was just asking to confirm the different roles CF Diego and Kubernetes would play in a cloud environment. If I understand everything you've told me so far, CF Diego would be used for: building, versioning and deploying my Docker containers. But Kubernetes, as you say, is for "orchestrating" between "multiple hosts". I'm asking: **What do you mean by "orchestrating", and by "multiple hosts"?** Thanks again so much!

Comment: @smeeb Both CF and Openshift are designed to work on top of a pool of available compute resources (VMs or servers). Orchestration is the running a series of actions in a particular order. Can I politely point out that the original question is answered?